# How can I know if my pc has the right drivers?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, drivers, sound, intel-graphics

I'm new to linux, I got myself an Ubuntu 10.04

I think that the audio drivers aren't working well, since the sound is not as good as before (on windows).
I also think the graphic drivers aren't working well, since the pc freezes after ubuntu login, if I set the "visual effects" on anything higher than "none".

I have a 945gct-m2 motherboard with the built-in graphic card and audio card.

How do I know if i have the right drivers, or check if the hardware is working correctly?

PS: remember that I'm new to ubuntu so I don't have all the knowledge required.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking Intel drivers Just Work out of the box. Here are some things you can do to help diagnose the problem. In `System -> Administration -> System Testing` you can run the hardware tester:

[image]

From this menu you can run just the test you need for video (or you can run them all and submit them, which would submit your hardware information)

The Ubuntu X team has a whole [set of pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/) on how to debug your problem, it sounds like the page for [Intel Performance Problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/IntelPerformance) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I ran the tests and everything worked well except for the "xrandr_cycle" test, since i wasn't able to see all the screens displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System/Administration/Additional Drivers, if nothing appears, you are using the current "best" driver, if something appear, you maybe have restricted/closedsource alternative (created by vendors)

Comment: I think you mean System/Administration/hardware drivers, which shows the proprietary drivers, if so, then it shows "none"
But if I have the best drivers, then how come I have trouble with the audio and graphics?